# Excel - Formula to filter column based on variable time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that needs split based on "morning" and "evening" although the morning and evening times move every day (it's based on sidereal day). Calling them morning and evening is a little deceiving though because eventually the time will creep into the next day and I want to keep the groups distinct. It is more accurate to call them group 1 and group 2. It just so happens that they are around 12 hours apart so it looks like you can just separate based on time of day but once the later group creeps into the AM hours, it would start to get counted as "morning" and the earlier group would roll into the afternoon and be counted as "afternoon" See screenshot below for example data.

[image: screenshot]

I need them split so I can perform operations on the value column so I can distinguish the values in the first group from the values in the second group. I thought of doing some sort of flip flop algorithm based on the previous cell but there may be a more elegant way to do it. Also, it's not shown on the example data but sometimes the day may skip but the times more or less continue in the same pattern of increasing by 3-5 minutes each day.

Comment: If the times in your list are sidereal times AM is separated from PM by the mid-day mark, meaning 12 noon. If the times in your list are normal times and you want to separate them according to sidereal AM and PM you need additional information not included in your sample data, to wit, the difference between sidereal and normal time on a given day or even on a given part of day. In fact, you would need to convert the normal times in the list to sidereal times and then sort by 12 noon.

Answer (score 1):

A date with a time stamp is stored as a number in Excel. Days are stored as whole numbers, time is stored in decimals. So, disregarding the date part, look at the decimal of the number and determine if that is before or after the time you want.

0.5 for example is midday, or 12 noon. So if the decimal part of A1 is less than 0.5, the time stamp would be in the morning.

```
=if(A1-int(A1)<0.5,"before noon","after noon")
```

It is not clear from your question how sidereal relates to the data in your sample.

Comment: That's a cool trick that I may be able to use elsewhere but I failed to explain that the times creep into the next day so they aren't technically morning and afternoon. They are more like Group 1 and Group 2. Each group is separated by about 12 hours but they need to stay in their group. I will update the question to be more clear.